# rx-java2 exception handling

Tags: rx-java2

I am using flowable iterator and process the request for each item from the iterable. If any exception thrown how to find out for which input the exception occurs.

e.g:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(userList)
            .flatMap(d -> Flowable.fromCallable(() -> getClaimStatus(d))
            ).map(d -> updateClaimStatus(d))
            .subscribe(d -> System.out.println("Processed"),
                    err -> System.err.println(err.getMessage()));
```

I just want to print for which user the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try-catch inside the `fromCallable`/`map` and throw a wrapper exception of your choice:

```java
Flowable.fromIterable(userList)
    .flatMap(d -> Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
       try {
           return getClaimStatus(d);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           throw new Exception("User: " + d, ex);
       }
    }))
    .map(d -> {
        try {
            return updateClaimStatus(d);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           throw new Exception("User: " + d, ex);
       }
    })
    .subscribe(
        d -> System.out.println("Processed"),
        err -> System.err.println(err.getMessage())
    );
```